# Apache Beam pipeline metrices

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline which runs on Google Dataflow and reads from a pub/sub. I use metrices, mostly counters, to get an idea of how many events were processed.
The general idea is that it reads protobuf messages from the pubsub, deserializes them and dumps the into different BigQuery tables.
I have a counter in the ParDo that does the de-serialization and also counter in the ParDo that does the inserts into the BQ. Most of the time, the difference between the end counter and the start counter is big, like around 40%. The wall time on the pipeline steps is always increasing, but the Data Freshness and System Latency for the pipeline is really low, like around 30 sec...

Why is this happening thos? Is is something related to counters?
[image]

You can see the `size_ok` metric which is the first metric from the pipeline, and if you sum up all of the below metrices, you don't even get close to this number.

My question is, why is there such a big difference between size_ok metric, which is the total number of events that started to be processed and the `inserts` metrics. If you sum up all the insert metrics, there is no way that they sum up to 6,6 mln events as shown by size_ok

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you have questions about? Are you asking why there might be a disparity in the size_ok vs inserts metrics? Or are you worried about the wall time/data freshness/system latency metrics? And if its the latter, what about those metrics do you find concerning?

Comment: Do you use with timestamp id in your PubSub read?
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.26.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withTimestampAttribute-java.lang.String-

If yes could the difference be late data?

Comment: I don't use it because the messages are protobuf serialized bytes... So I first need to decode them and I'm using the timestamp from te decoded message.